# Unable to perform Drag and Drop- Webdriver Java

Tags: java, testing, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I have tried to search a text in google images and then drag the element and drop. However it is not performing the same. When we manually move the mouse some action is occurring but drag and drop function is not performed.

```
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://images.google.com/");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Apple");
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
    WebElement drag= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html body#gsr.srp div#main div#cnt.mdm div#rcnt div.col div#center_col div#res.med div#topstuff div#ifbc.prc div#ifb.prs a.rg_fbl div.rg_bb div.rg_bb_i div.rg_bb_layout div.rg_di img.rg_i"));
    WebElement drop= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html body#gsr.srp div#tphdr.tphdr div#mngb div#gb.gb_1b div.gb_Ab div.gb_k div#gbq div#gbq2.gbt div#gbqfw.gbqfr form#gbqf.gb_Nb fieldset#gbqff.gbqff div#gbfwa.gbqfwa div#gbqfqw.gbqfqw div#gbqfqwb.gbqfqwc table#gs_id0.gstl_0 tbody tr td#gs_tti0.gsib_a div#gs_lc0 input#gs_htif0.gbqfif"));
    Actions builder= new Actions(driver);
    Action dragelement= builder.clickAndHold(drag).build();
    dragelement.perform();
    Action dropelement=builder.moveToElement(drop).release(drop).build();
    dropelement.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();    
driver.get("http://images.google.com/");  

driver.switchTo().frame(0);   

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    

WebElement dragElement = driver.findElement(By.id("draggable"));  

WebElement dropElement = driver.findElement(By.id("droppable")); 

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);  // Configure the Action  

Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(dragElement)
                            .moveToElement(dropElement)
                            .release(dropElement).build();  // Get the action  

dragAndDrop.perform(); // Execute the Action
```

Comment: I have tried both ways but still its working in the same manner. When mouse is manually moved it shows some drag action but drag and drop is not performed.

Answer (score 0):

code to drag this element to an **offset** is

> WebElement draggable = browser.findElement(By.id("draggable")); new
>   Actions(browser).dragAndDropBy(draggable, 200, 10).build().perform();